# Spring Boot - No AuthenticationProvider found for authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring-boot, security

version of spring boot : 3.1.2

Currently i implement a simple spring boot based application which involve spring security, as shown below.
However, upon when i try login using the form, i got "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken".

Question: Why do i get such error? I thought by default, DaoAuthenticationProvider will be instantiated by Spring Boot and it will  auto pick up whatever custom UserDetailsService bean and PasswordEncoder bean we configured.

Note: Pls do let me know also if i post in the wrong forum.

```
@Configuration
public class DemoSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        var encoders = new HashMap<String, PasswordEncoder>(
                Map.of("bcrypt",new BCryptPasswordEncoder(),
                        "noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        );

        var e = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("noop", encoders);
        return e;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsManager() {

        UserDetails susan = User.builder()
                .username("susan")
                .password("{noop}test123")
                .roles("EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER", "ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(susan);
    }
 


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer ->
                   configurer.requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

        );

http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }


}
```

[image]

`

Comment: can you try to disable the `passwordEncoder()` method by commenting the `@Bean` Annotation? I think as soon as you override standard configs, you need to add more code to make it work. Checkout also these tutorials: https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring You can also checkout some git repos and test it out.

Comment: disabling passwordEncoder() as bean, still have same error. The error will only goes away after I manually define DaoAuthenticationProvider bean.  However, for the purpose of learning, i just don't understand why there is a need to create the provider bean.  By default, spring boot autoconfigured DaoAuthenticationProvider as bean.  I understand from online research, that even if we create our own UserDetailsService bean,  the AuthenticationProvider should still be automatically created for us.   It will NOT use the userdetailservice bean it autoconfigured, instead use the one we create

Comment: I try searching for spring boot and spring security source codes in github to see if can get any clue, under what circumstances is the DaoAuthenticationProvider not autoconfigured

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause.

If you create your own UserDetailsService bean, there is no need to manually define a bean for AuthenticationProvider, cos by default a DaoAuthenticationProvider bean will be automatically created for us, which will automatically pick up your defined UserDetailsService bean.

But if you define 2 or more UserDetailsService beans, then u need to define your own Authenticationprovider. I made a mistake, as i don't realize I have another class that implements UserDetailsService interface and annotated with @Service , which create a second UserDetailsService bean.

Comment: Do you have a source to your finding? The docu seem to be missleading: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/index.html where it also says to implement a DaoAuthenticationProvider. But also, if I dont provide such a bean, it works as expected. Can you please provide a link to your finding?

Comment: Hi, i have no source for my finding. it is purely based on my hand-on experiment. Let me also take a look at the document u post

Comment: @AnnaKlein By the way, which part of the webpage (for the link u post) mentions "must implement DaoAuthenticationProvider", if we create our own custom UserDetailsService